# Clarification of a step in a solution.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing

The question and its solution are given below:

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

But I don't understand why in this solution $\{ f_{n}\} \rightarrow f$ pointwise $a.e.$ on $E.$ Could anyone explains this for me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every real number $x$ there exists $n_0$ such that $x <n$ for all $n \geq n_0$, so $f_n(x)=0$ for all $n \geq n_0$. This means $f_n(x) \to 0$ for every $x$, in particular, for almost all $x$.